# How to use some function on new SQLite version

Tags: sqlite

First, I'm looking a way to change my sqlite3 android device's current version from 3.7 to 3.8. That version has some function I needed. Then, I found the [Latest SQLite binary for April 2014](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2730422), and replaced my old sqlite3 with the new sqlite3 (3.8.4.3) in `system/xbin`. I checked my android sqlite3 version with my android terminal and yes, it works, my sqlite3 version is now sqlite 3.8.4.3,

I'm trying to use a recursive function in sqlite3 3.8.4.3 from [this doc](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html)

It works when running on `cmd` from windows, and android terminal from android devices,
but it doesn't work when I'm trying to implement it on my example app. 
Is there anything I missed? Or some library that I have to add to my project app?

Comment: I'm curious, if you have to hack SQLite into a non-standard version, what makes you think your application will run on any phone other than your own? It's not like you can forcibly upgrade their SQLite version. Or is this not a concern for you?

Comment: i'm not to trying to developed an app for sale, for now on it just an app for my homework,

Comment: Sure, but that app for your homework isn't going to work on the grader's phone either. Working within a standard is usually part of a homework assignment.

Comment: i'm sure it is, but this curiosity keep me still looking and looking, i've been looking for a couple day,

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is an embedded library and is typically compiled into whatever program is using it.

The `sqlite3` command-line shell contains its own copy of SQLite.

To change the SQLite version available to Android apps, you have to replace the SQLite in the system libraries and recompile them.

Comment: how to do that ? where i find sqlite3 3.8 libraries ?